# eval() function in PHP, how to make this work properly on the website?

Tags: php, html, eval

I have a problem with eval() function. Please do not comment something like "Don't use eval" or anything of this kind of thing, as this is not helpful. I have a very good reason to use eval().

Basically I am getting a value from a text field in html on my web page as input code to be executed, like so:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

Then, am passing that value to eval function in the html body, like so:

```
eval($code);
```

the results are displayed like this:

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

the above is displayed string. I want this to execute the html part of it is well. Funny thing is if I try this in a different file like this:

```
<?php
$code = "echo '<h1><b>TEST</b></h1>';";
eval($code);
?>
```

I get the desired result, which is a proper processed html element h1 with "TEST" in it.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in `$_POST['code']`? My guess is that you're not sending what you think you're sending.

Comment: I tried echoing it and it is basically this:
echo '<h1><b>test</b></h1>';

Comment: Basically? Or *exactly*?

Comment: exactly. This is what I get when I echo the value of $_POST['code'] . I inspected the element is well and the contents are the above.

Comment: If you see the literal HTML when you echo it, that means the variable contains HTML entities. Use View Source to see what it actually contains.

Comment: &lt;h1&gt;test&lt;/h1&gt;  ... does this mean I need to decode the string before using it in eval()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['code']` apparently contains HTML entity codes, e.g.

```
"echo '&lt;h1&gt;test&lt;/h1&gt';"
```

You need to decode it before calling `eval`.

```
eval(html_entity_decode($_POST['code']));
```

Comment: Thank you ! This worked perfectly! I was suspecting the character not being decoded since they appear in that manner inside the textbox, but was unsure since they were displayed correctly after that. Once again thank you!